# Bash: Last Returncode filling variables

Tags: bash, variables, return-value

at bash I can get Returncode of last Command with $?.
This does not work by filling a variable as shown:

```
VARIABLE=`echo "My great Text"`
```

Return Code is allways 0.
How can I get the Returncode of the Command?

Comment: Why would you believe that `echo` would return something other than 0 there?

Comment: __$?__ tells only the last command status(0 for success >0 for failure), it doesn't matter it is assigning a variable or not.

Comment: Bad example with echo. My Example: *VARIABLE=\`script.sh\`* The script can return Returcode greater 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VARIABLE in your example will get the output of the command

> echo $VARIABLE
>
> My great Text

You need to get the result value after that with $?

`echo` will always return 0 since no reason it will fail here.

In general, you check the status like so:

```
output=`script.sh`
retval="$?"
echo "Script output is: " $output
echo "Script return value is: " $retval
```

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002

Note, this will read the return value of the script if you used `exit <code>` (I believe it is the case). If the return value is the output of the script,

> retval=`script.sh'

should be used (but then it is not a return value per se)

Comment: Bad Example. Its a script: variable=`script.sh`

Comment: Example was OK, however I've expanded it with further explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Your code already does what you ask.  In order to see it, you just have to replace `echo` with `script.sh` as you mention in your comments or with some other command that can return a non zero status.  `$?` will be set to the exit status of the subshell used for your variable assignment.

For example, this correctly reports that `$?` is 1:

```
FOO=`echo "My great Text" ; false` ; echo $?
```

Similarly, this reports that `$?` is 0:

```
FOO=`echo "My great Text" ; true` ; echo $?
```

Answer (score 0):

See the next examples:

```
serga@XXX:~$ false
serga@XXX:~$ v="My great text $?"
serga@XXX:~$ echo $v
My great text 1
serga@XXX:~$ true
serga@XXX:~$ v="My great text $?"
serga@XXX:~$ echo $v
My great text 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, problem was, that the Command does not return the right value :-(
Thank you for support.